# WSO2 Governance Registry, Docker and boot2docker

Tags: wso2, docker, boot2docker

I'm using `boot2docker` on OSX 10.10 to try to run the WSO2 governance registry.  I cannot reach the app from the host machine (OSX).

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM dockerfile/java:openjdk-7-jdk
MAINTAINER Andrew Matthews

COPY wso2greg-4.6.0.zip /opt/

RUN unzip /opt/wso2greg-4.6.0.zip -d /opt && \
    rm /opt/wso2greg-4.6.0.zip

EXPOSE 9443
CMD ["/opt/wso2greg-4.6.0/bin/wso2server.sh"]
```

This follows a pattern used by others on docker.io for other wso2 apps.

I built it with:

```
docker build -t="usmsnp/wso2greg" .
```

and ran it with

```
docker run -i -t -P usmsnp/wso2greg
```

everything seems to proceed nicely - I get as far as the wso2 announcement:

```
Mgt Console URL  : https://172.17.0.27:9443/carbon/
```

I have the *boot2docker vm* IP address aliased as dockerhost in my /etc/hosts file, and when I navigate to `https://dockerhost:9443/carbon/` using curl I get connection refused.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE: 2014-11-28**

When I deploy the image to AWS using tutum, it works.  So, mission accomplished, I suppose.  But I'm still confused about why it doesn't work. I understand that boot2docker requires a different IP address, but I used that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `docker run -P` you're telling Docker to allocate a random port on the Docker daemon host - not to use `9443`.

So in this case, you'll need to run `docker ports <containerid>` to find out what port its been mapped to.

alternativly, you need to use `docker run -p 9443:9443 ...` to tell Docker to map the external `9443` to the container's `9443`

Comment: strangely I did try `-p 9443:9443` but it didn't work. But I was able to find the port that was used with docker ports.  Thanks.